# parsley validate birth date

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have a form which checks if the user is old enough to contribute to a contest.

Is there a validation solution for this with [parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/)?

I thought the easiest way would be to just check the year and leave it by that with:

```
data-parsley-max="1984"
```

But is there also a solution to check the full date and not only the year:

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No support yet for dates, sorry. See [this issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/814)